# Input and Arguments

Tags: python

I've been using input a lot in a program recently and I've noticed that I can't have multiple arguments in the same line, like I can with print commands. If I tried to type, say:

```
num = int(input("Number?"))

answer = input("Your number was", num)
```

I would get an error message saying that it expected 1 positional argument and got 2. Why does this happen and how can I work around it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with that second line?

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `input()` only takes one argument which is the prompt.

You have provided an additional argument (`num`).

Also as you are trying to print the `num` back, you just need `print()`:

```
print("Your number was {}".format(num))
```

Comment: Also should note that for output, OP should not be using the `input` function, but simply a `print` statement.